# Laravel 4 belongsToMany with where condition

Tags: php, laravel-4, many-to-many

I have the following database structure:
[image]

Cards table have a many to many relationship with types, types can have one of thoses 3 metatypes:

- supertype
- subtype
- type

In my Card model, I would like to have the following methods:

- types() -> "... where types.metatype='type'"
- supertypes() -> "... where types.metatype='supertype'"
- subtypes() -> "... where types.metatype='subtype'"

Is it possible to add a where on the types table (not on the pivot) to achieve this ?

Prior to that, I had 3 distinct tables:

- cards_types
- cards_supertypes
- cards_subtypes

But that doesn't seemed a very good idea, because the metatype data is already present in the types table, so I rather not "repeat" this information by duplicating the relation tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
public function supertype() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Card')->where('metatype','=','supertype');
}

public function subtype() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Card')->where('metatype','=','subtype');
}

public function type() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Card')->where('metatype','=','type');
}
```

Comment: thanks, I solved the problem in another way but your answers indeed works :)

Comment: Could you tell us how? Thanks :)